# Show certain image from image sprite

Tags: c++, windows, image, wxwidgets

I have wrote a class which will be responsible for the image buttons handling:

```
#include "ImageButton.h"

ImageButton::ImageButton()
{
    // main constructor
}

ImageButton::ImageButton(wxWindow* parent, const wxString& buttonPath)
    : wxStaticBitmap(parent, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap(buttonPath, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(0, 0), wxDefaultSize)
{
    Refresh();
}

ImageButton::~ImageButton()
{
    // ...
}
```

This is very beginning and basic. However, I have just found out that there is probably no possibility to resize the image (not changing it's dimensions).

This is how the image looks like:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve right here is tell `wxStaticBitmap` to display only *one* close square button at the time (so then I could make a mouse over/click event handlers for it). Setting it's size won't work here and thats not what I want.

Is it possible to crop the image at certain dimensions in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "no possibility to resize the image"? It is possible to resize it, of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two images from it. One of the ways to do it is to use `wxImage::Resize` (first make a copy of the original image). Second way is to use `wxBitmap::GetSubBitmap` (you need to convert the wxImage to wxBitmap - this can be done by simple assignment). It really depends what you want to achieve and what is more convenient to you.

Comment: Amazing. Looks like the `wxBitmap::GetSubBitmap` is exactly what I need right here. Thanks. Btw. Is it possible to create a `wxImage` and the convert it into the `wxBitmap`? I am curious because I've noticed that `wxImage` has more image-manipulation methods available.

Comment: To convert wxImage to wxBitmap you can just assign it `wxBitmap bmp = mywxImage`. To convert it the other way: use `wxBitmap::  ConvertToImage`.